Поставить цвет в умный фильтр bitrix

Сайт на битриксе для фильтрации используем catalog.smart.filter
Вот так сейчас выглядит фильтр по цвету, данные подтягиваются из hiload блока с библиотекой цветов, у которых должно быть заложено изображение и если его добавить оно появляется

Но вот вопрос. В Hiload блоках есть XML_Id с hex кодом цвета, как мне его добавить на фон этих элементов, как его вывести?

Прикладываю код, где выводится нужный элемент в template.php в catalog.smart.filter
case "H"://CHECKBOXES_WITH_PICTURES_AND_LABELS
?>
<?foreach ($arItem["VALUES"] as $val => $ar):?>
    <input
        style="display: none"
        type="checkbox"
        name="<?=$ar["CONTROL_NAME"]?>"
        id="<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>"
        value="<?=$ar["HTML_VALUE"]?>"
        <? echo $ar["CHECKED"]? 'checked="checked"': '' ?>
    />
    <?
    $class = "";
    if ($ar["CHECKED"])
        $class.= " active";
    if ($ar["DISABLED"])
        $class.= " disabled";
    ?>
    <label for="<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>" data-role="label_<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>" class="bx_filter_param_label<?=$class?>" onclick="smartFilter.keyup(BX('<?=CUtil::JSEscape($ar["CONTROL_ID"])?>')); BX.toggleClass(this, 'active');">
        <span class="bx_filter_param_btn bx_color_sl">
            <?if (isset($ar["FILE"]) && !empty($ar["FILE"]["SRC"])):?>
                <span class="bx_filter_btn_color_icon" style="background-image:url('<?=$ar["FILE"]["SRC"]?>');"></span>
            <?else:?>
                <span class="bx_filter_btn_color_icon" style="background: #<?=$ar["XML_ID"]?>;"></span>
            <?endif?>
        </span>
        <span class="bx_filter_param_text" title="<?=$ar["VALUE"];?>"><?=$ar["VALUE"];?><?
        if ($arParams["DISPLAY_ELEMENT_COUNT"] !== "N" && isset($ar["ELEMENT_COUNT"])):
            ?> (<span data-role="count_<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>"><? echo $ar["ELEMENT_COUNT"]; ?></span>)<?
        endif;?></span>
    </label>
<?endforeach?>
<?
break;

И на всякий случай приложу весь template.php в catalog.smart.filter
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);

$templateData = array(
    'TEMPLATE_THEME' => $this->GetFolder().'/themes/'.$arParams['TEMPLATE_THEME'].'/colors.css',
    'TEMPLATE_CLASS' => 'bx_'.$arParams['TEMPLATE_THEME']
);
?>
<div class="bx_filter <?=$templateData["TEMPLATE_CLASS"]?> bx_horizontal">
    <div class="bx_filter_section">
        <div class="bx_filter_title"><?echo GetMessage("CT_BCSF_FILTER_TITLE")?></div>
        <form name="<?echo $arResult["FILTER_NAME"]."_form"?>" action="<?echo $arResult["FORM_ACTION"]?>" method="get" class="smartfilter">
            <?foreach($arResult["HIDDEN"] as $arItem):?>
            <input type="hidden" name="<?echo $arItem["CONTROL_NAME"]?>" id="<?echo $arItem["CONTROL_ID"]?>" value="<?echo $arItem["HTML_VALUE"]?>" />
            <?endforeach;
            //prices
            foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $key=>$arItem)
            {
                $key = $arItem["ENCODED_ID"];
                if(isset($arItem["PRICE"])):
                    if ($arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["VALUE"] - $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"] <= 0)
                        continue;
                    ?>
                    <div class="bx_filter_parameters_box active">
                        <span class="bx_filter_container_modef"></span>
                        <div class="bx_filter_parameters_box_title" onclick="smartFilter.hideFilterProps(this)"><?=$arItem["NAME"]?></div>
                        <div class="bx_filter_block">
                            <div class="bx_filter_parameters_box_container">
                                <div class="bx_filter_parameters_box_container_block">
                                    <div class="bx_filter_input_container">
                                        <input
                                            class="min-price"
                                            type="text"
                                            name="<?echo $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["CONTROL_NAME"]?>"
                                            id="<?echo $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["CONTROL_ID"]?>"
                                            value="<?echo $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["HTML_VALUE"]?>"
                                            size="5"
                                            onkeyup="smartFilter.keyup(this)"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="bx_filter_parameters_box_container_block">
                                    <div class="bx_filter_input_container">
                                        <input
                                            class="max-price"
                                            type="text"
                                            name="<?echo $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["CONTROL_NAME"]?>"
                                            id="<?echo $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["CONTROL_ID"]?>"
                                            value="<?echo $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["HTML_VALUE"]?>"
                                            size="5"
                                            onkeyup="smartFilter.keyup(this)"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="clear: both;"></div>

                                <div class="bx_ui_slider_track" id="drag_track_<?=$key?>">
                                    <?
                                    $price1 = $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"];
                                    $price2 = $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"] + round(($arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["VALUE"] - $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"])/4);
                                    $price3 = $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"] + round(($arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["VALUE"] - $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"])/2);
                                    $price4 = $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"] + round((($arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["VALUE"] - $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"])*3)/4);
                                    $price5 = $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["VALUE"];
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="bx_ui_slider_part p1"><span><?=$price1?></span></div>
                                    <div class="bx_ui_slider_part p2"><span><?=$price2?></span></div>
                                    <div class="bx_ui_slider_part p3"><span><?=$price3?></span></div>
                                    <div class="bx_ui_slider_part p4"><span><?=$price4?></span></div>
                                    <div class="bx_ui_slider_part p5"><span><?=$price5?></span></div>

                                    <div class="bx_ui_slider_pricebar_VD" style="left: 0;right: 0;" id="colorUnavailableActive_<?=$key?>"></div>
                                    <div class="bx_ui_slider_pricebar_VN" style="left: 0;right: 0;" id="colorAvailableInactive_<?=$key?>"></div>
                                    <div class="bx_ui_slider_pricebar_V"  style="left: 0;right: 0;" id="colorAvailableActive_<?=$key?>"></div>
                                    <div class="bx_ui_slider_range" id="drag_tracker_<?=$key?>"  style="left: 0%; right: 0%;">
                                        <a class="bx_ui_slider_handle left"  style="left:0;" href="javascript:void(0)" id="left_slider_<?=$key?>"></a>
                                        <a class="bx_ui_slider_handle right" style="right:0;" href="javascript:void(0)" id="right_slider_<?=$key?>"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="opacity: 0;height: 1px;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?
                    $precision = 2;
                    if (Bitrix\Main\Loader::includeModule("currency"))
                    {
                        $res = CCurrencyLang::GetFormatDescription($arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["CURRENCY"]);
                        $precision = $res['DECIMALS'];
                    }
                    $arJsParams = array(
                        "leftSlider" => 'left_slider_'.$key,
                        "rightSlider" => 'right_slider_'.$key,
                        "tracker" => "drag_tracker_".$key,
                        "trackerWrap" => "drag_track_".$key,
                        "minInputId" => $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["CONTROL_ID"],
                        "maxInputId" => $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["CONTROL_ID"],
                        "minPrice" => $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"],
                        "maxPrice" => $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["VALUE"],
                        "curMinPrice" => $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["HTML_VALUE"],
                        "curMaxPrice" => $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["HTML_VALUE"],
                        "fltMinPrice" => intval($arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["FILTERED_VALUE"]) ? $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["FILTERED_VALUE"] : $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"] ,
                        "fltMaxPrice" => intval($arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["FILTERED_VALUE"]) ? $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["FILTERED_VALUE"] : $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["VALUE"],
                        "precision" => $precision,
                        "colorUnavailableActive" => 'colorUnavailableActive_'.$key,
                        "colorAvailableActive" => 'colorAvailableActive_'.$key,
                        "colorAvailableInactive" => 'colorAvailableInactive_'.$key,
                    );
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        BX.ready(function(){
                            window['trackBar<?=$key?>'] = new BX.Iblock.SmartFilter(<?=CUtil::PhpToJSObject($arJsParams)?>);
                        });
                    </script>
                <?endif;
            }

            //not prices
            foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $key=>$arItem)
            {
                if(
                    empty($arItem["VALUES"])
                    || isset($arItem["PRICE"])
                )
                    continue;

                if (
                    $arItem["DISPLAY_TYPE"] == "A"
                    && (
                        $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["VALUE"] - $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"] <= 0
                    )
                )
                    continue;
                ?>
                <div class="bx_filter_parameters_box <?if ($arItem["DISPLAY_EXPANDED"]== "Y"):?>active<?endif?>">
                    <span class="bx_filter_container_modef"></span>
                    <div class="bx_filter_parameters_box_title" onclick="smartFilter.hideFilterProps(this)"><?=$arItem["NAME"]?></div>
                    <div class="bx_filter_block">
                        <div class="bx_filter_parameters_box_container">
                        <?
                        $arCur = current($arItem["VALUES"]);
                        switch ($arItem["DISPLAY_TYPE"])
                        {
                            case "A"://NUMBERS_WITH_SLIDER
                                ?>
                                <div class="bx_filter_parameters_box_container_block">
                                    <div class="bx_filter_input_container">
                                        <input
                                            class="min-price"
                                            type="text"
                                            name="<?echo $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["CONTROL_NAME"]?>"
                                            id="<?echo $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["CONTROL_ID"]?>"
                                            value="<?echo $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["HTML_VALUE"]?>"
                                            size="5"
                                            onkeyup="smartFilter.keyup(this)"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="bx_filter_parameters_box_container_block">
                                    <div class="bx_filter_input_container">
                                        <input
                                            class="max-price"
                                            type="text"
                                            name="<?echo $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["CONTROL_NAME"]?>"
                                            id="<?echo $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["CONTROL_ID"]?>"
                                            value="<?echo $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["HTML_VALUE"]?>"
                                            size="5"
                                            onkeyup="smartFilter.keyup(this)"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="clear: both;"></div>

                                <div class="bx_ui_slider_track" id="drag_track_<?=$key?>">
                                    <?
                                    $value1 = $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"];
                                    $value2 = $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"] + round(($arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["VALUE"] - $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"])/4);
                                    $value3 = $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"] + round(($arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["VALUE"] - $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"])/2);
                                    $value4 = $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"] + round((($arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["VALUE"] - $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"])*3)/4);
                                    $value5 = $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["VALUE"];
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="bx_ui_slider_part p1"><span><?=$value1?></span></div>
                                    <div class="bx_ui_slider_part p2"><span><?=$value2?></span></div>
                                    <div class="bx_ui_slider_part p3"><span><?=$value3?></span></div>
                                    <div class="bx_ui_slider_part p4"><span><?=$value4?></span></div>
                                    <div class="bx_ui_slider_part p5"><span><?=$value5?></span></div>

                                    <div class="bx_ui_slider_pricebar_VD" style="left: 0;right: 0;" id="colorUnavailableActive_<?=$key?>"></div>
                                    <div class="bx_ui_slider_pricebar_VN" style="left: 0;right: 0;" id="colorAvailableInactive_<?=$key?>"></div>
                                    <div class="bx_ui_slider_pricebar_V"  style="left: 0;right: 0;" id="colorAvailableActive_<?=$key?>"></div>
                                    <div class="bx_ui_slider_range"     id="drag_tracker_<?=$key?>"  style="left: 0;right: 0;">
                                        <a class="bx_ui_slider_handle left"  style="left:0;" href="javascript:void(0)" id="left_slider_<?=$key?>"></a>
                                        <a class="bx_ui_slider_handle right" style="right:0;" href="javascript:void(0)" id="right_slider_<?=$key?>"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?
                                $arJsParams = array(
                                    "leftSlider" => 'left_slider_'.$key,
                                    "rightSlider" => 'right_slider_'.$key,
                                    "tracker" => "drag_tracker_".$key,
                                    "trackerWrap" => "drag_track_".$key,
                                    "minInputId" => $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["CONTROL_ID"],
                                    "maxInputId" => $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["CONTROL_ID"],
                                    "minPrice" => $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"],
                                    "maxPrice" => $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["VALUE"],
                                    "curMinPrice" => $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["HTML_VALUE"],
                                    "curMaxPrice" => $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["HTML_VALUE"],
                                    "fltMinPrice" => intval($arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["FILTERED_VALUE"]) ? $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["FILTERED_VALUE"] : $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"] ,
                                    "fltMaxPrice" => intval($arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["FILTERED_VALUE"]) ? $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["FILTERED_VALUE"] : $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["VALUE"],
                                    "precision" => $arItem["DECIMALS"]? $arItem["DECIMALS"]: 0,
                                    "colorUnavailableActive" => 'colorUnavailableActive_'.$key,
                                    "colorAvailableActive" => 'colorAvailableActive_'.$key,
                                    "colorAvailableInactive" => 'colorAvailableInactive_'.$key,
                                );
                                ?>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    BX.ready(function(){
                                        window['trackBar<?=$key?>'] = new BX.Iblock.SmartFilter(<?=CUtil::PhpToJSObject($arJsParams)?>);
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <?
                                break;
                            case "B"://NUMBERS
                                ?>
                                <div class="bx_filter_parameters_box_container_block"><div class="bx_filter_input_container">
                                    <input
                                        class="min-price"
                                        type="text"
                                        name="<?echo $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["CONTROL_NAME"]?>"
                                        id="<?echo $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["CONTROL_ID"]?>"
                                        value="<?echo $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["HTML_VALUE"]?>"
                                        size="5"
                                        onkeyup="smartFilter.keyup(this)"
                                        />
                                </div></div>
                                <div class="bx_filter_parameters_box_container_block"><div class="bx_filter_input_container">
                                    <input
                                        class="max-price"
                                        type="text"
                                        name="<?echo $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["CONTROL_NAME"]?>"
                                        id="<?echo $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["CONTROL_ID"]?>"
                                        value="<?echo $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["HTML_VALUE"]?>"
                                        size="5"
                                        onkeyup="smartFilter.keyup(this)"
                                        />
                                </div></div>
                                <?
                                break;
                            case "G"://CHECKBOXES_WITH_PICTURES
                                ?>
                                <?foreach ($arItem["VALUES"] as $val => $ar):?>
                                    <input
                                        style="display: none"
                                        type="checkbox"
                                        name="<?=$ar["CONTROL_NAME"]?>"
                                        id="<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>"
                                        value="<?=$ar["HTML_VALUE"]?>"
                                        <? echo $ar["CHECKED"]? 'checked="checked"': '' ?>
                                    />
                                    <?
                                    $class = "";
                                    if ($ar["CHECKED"])
                                        $class.= " active";
                                    if ($ar["DISABLED"])
                                        $class.= " disabled";
                                    ?>
                                    <label for="<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>" data-role="label_<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>" class="bx_filter_param_label dib<?=$class?>" onclick="smartFilter.keyup(BX('<?=CUtil::JSEscape($ar["CONTROL_ID"])?>')); BX.toggleClass(this, 'active');">
                                        <span class="bx_filter_param_btn bx_color_sl">
                                            <?if (isset($ar["FILE"]) && !empty($ar["FILE"]["SRC"])):?>
                                            <span class="bx_filter_btn_color_icon" style="background-image:url('<?=$ar["FILE"]["SRC"]?>');"></span>
                                            <?endif?>
                                        </span>
                                    </label>
                                <?endforeach?>
                                <?
                                break;
                            case "H"://CHECKBOXES_WITH_PICTURES_AND_LABELS
                                ?>
                                <?foreach ($arItem["VALUES"] as $val => $ar):?>
                                    <input
                                        style="display: none"
                                        type="checkbox"
                                        name="<?=$ar["CONTROL_NAME"]?>"
                                        id="<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>"
                                        value="<?=$ar["HTML_VALUE"]?>"
                                        <? echo $ar["CHECKED"]? 'checked="checked"': '' ?>
                                    />
                                    <?
                                    $class = "";
                                    if ($ar["CHECKED"])
                                        $class.= " active";
                                    if ($ar["DISABLED"])
                                        $class.= " disabled";
                                    ?>
                                    <label for="<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>" data-role="label_<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>" class="bx_filter_param_label<?=$class?>" onclick="smartFilter.keyup(BX('<?=CUtil::JSEscape($ar["CONTROL_ID"])?>')); BX.toggleClass(this, 'active');">
                                        <span class="bx_filter_param_btn bx_color_sl">
                                            <?if (isset($ar["FILE"]) && !empty($ar["FILE"]["SRC"])):?>
                                                <span class="bx_filter_btn_color_icon" style="background-image:url('<?=$ar["FILE"]["SRC"]?>');"></span>
                                            <?else:?>
                                                <span class="bx_filter_btn_color_icon" style="background: #<?=$ar["XML_ID"]?>;"></span>
                                            <?endif?>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="bx_filter_param_text" title="<?=$ar["VALUE"];?>"><?=$ar["VALUE"];?><?
                                        if ($arParams["DISPLAY_ELEMENT_COUNT"] !== "N" && isset($ar["ELEMENT_COUNT"])):
                                            ?> (<span data-role="count_<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>"><? echo $ar["ELEMENT_COUNT"]; ?></span>)<?
                                        endif;?></span>
                                    </label>
                                <?endforeach?>
                                <?
                                break;
                            case "P"://DROPDOWN
                                $checkedItemExist = false;
                                ?>
                                <div class="bx_filter_select_container">
                                    <div class="bx_filter_select_block" onclick="smartFilter.showDropDownPopup(this, '<?=CUtil::JSEscape($key)?>')">
                                        <div class="bx_filter_select_text" data-role="currentOption">
                                            <?
                                            foreach ($arItem["VALUES"] as $val => $ar)
                                            {
                                                if ($ar["CHECKED"])
                                                {
                                                    echo $ar["VALUE"];
                                                    $checkedItemExist = true;
                                                }
                                            }
                                            if (!$checkedItemExist)
                                            {
                                                echo GetMessage("CT_BCSF_FILTER_ALL");
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="bx_filter_select_arrow"></div>
                                        <input
                                            style="display: none"
                                            type="radio"
                                            name="<?=$arCur["CONTROL_NAME_ALT"]?>"
                                            id="<? echo "all_".$arCur["CONTROL_ID"] ?>"
                                            value=""
                                        />
                                        <?foreach ($arItem["VALUES"] as $val => $ar):?>
                                            <input
                                                style="display: none"
                                                type="radio"
                                                name="<?=$ar["CONTROL_NAME_ALT"]?>"
                                                id="<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>"
                                                value="<? echo $ar["HTML_VALUE_ALT"] ?>"
                                                <? echo $ar["CHECKED"]? 'checked="checked"': '' ?>
                                            />
                                        <?endforeach?>
                                        <div class="bx_filter_select_popup" data-role="dropdownContent" style="display: none;">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                    <label for="<?="all_".$arCur["CONTROL_ID"]?>" class="bx_filter_param_label" data-role="label_<?="all_".$arCur["CONTROL_ID"]?>" onclick="smartFilter.selectDropDownItem(this, '<?=CUtil::JSEscape("all_".$arCur["CONTROL_ID"])?>')">
                                                        <? echo GetMessage("CT_BCSF_FILTER_ALL"); ?>
                                                    </label>
                                                </li>
                                            <?
                                            foreach ($arItem["VALUES"] as $val => $ar):
                                                $class = "";
                                                if ($ar["CHECKED"])
                                                    $class.= " selected";
                                                if ($ar["DISABLED"])
                                                    $class.= " disabled";
                                            ?>
                                                <li>
                                                    <label for="<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>" class="bx_filter_param_label<?=$class?>" data-role="label_<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>" onclick="smartFilter.selectDropDownItem(this, '<?=CUtil::JSEscape($ar["CONTROL_ID"])?>')"><?=$ar["VALUE"]?></label>
                                                </li>
                                            <?endforeach?>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?
                                break;
                            case "R"://DROPDOWN_WITH_PICTURES_AND_LABELS
                                ?>
                                <div class="bx_filter_select_container">
                                    <div class="bx_filter_select_block" onclick="smartFilter.showDropDownPopup(this, '<?=CUtil::JSEscape($key)?>')">
                                        <div class="bx_filter_select_text" data-role="currentOption">
                                            <?
                                            $checkedItemExist = false;
                                            foreach ($arItem["VALUES"] as $val => $ar):
                                                if ($ar["CHECKED"])
                                                {
                                                ?>
                                                    <?if (isset($ar["FILE"]) && !empty($ar["FILE"]["SRC"])):?>
                                                        <span class="bx_filter_btn_color_icon" style="background-image:url('<?=$ar["FILE"]["SRC"]?>');"></span>
                                                    <?endif?>
                                                    <span class="bx_filter_param_text">
                                                        <?=$ar["VALUE"]?>
                                                    </span>
                                                <?
                                                    $checkedItemExist = true;
                                                }
                                            endforeach;
                                            if (!$checkedItemExist)
                                            {
                                                ?><span class="bx_filter_btn_color_icon all"></span> <?
                                                echo GetMessage("CT_BCSF_FILTER_ALL");
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="bx_filter_select_arrow"></div>
                                        <input
                                            style="display: none"
                                            type="radio"
                                            name="<?=$arCur["CONTROL_NAME_ALT"]?>"
                                            id="<? echo "all_".$arCur["CONTROL_ID"] ?>"
                                            value=""
                                        />
                                        <?foreach ($arItem["VALUES"] as $val => $ar):?>
                                            <input
                                                style="display: none"
                                                type="radio"
                                                name="<?=$ar["CONTROL_NAME_ALT"]?>"
                                                id="<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>"
                                                value="<?=$ar["HTML_VALUE_ALT"]?>"
                                                <? echo $ar["CHECKED"]? 'checked="checked"': '' ?>
                                            />
                                        <?endforeach?>
                                        <div class="bx_filter_select_popup" data-role="dropdownContent" style="display: none">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;padding-bottom: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">
                                                    <label for="<?="all_".$arCur["CONTROL_ID"]?>" class="bx_filter_param_label" data-role="label_<?="all_".$arCur["CONTROL_ID"]?>" onclick="smartFilter.selectDropDownItem(this, '<?=CUtil::JSEscape("all_".$arCur["CONTROL_ID"])?>')">
                                                        <span class="bx_filter_btn_color_icon all"></span>
                                                        <? echo GetMessage("CT_BCSF_FILTER_ALL"); ?>
                                                    </label>
                                                </li>
                                            <?
                                            foreach ($arItem["VALUES"] as $val => $ar):
                                                $class = "";
                                                if ($ar["CHECKED"])
                                                    $class.= " selected";
                                                if ($ar["DISABLED"])
                                                    $class.= " disabled";
                                            ?>
                                                <li>
                                                    <label for="<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>" data-role="label_<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>" class="bx_filter_param_label<?=$class?>" onclick="smartFilter.selectDropDownItem(this, '<?=CUtil::JSEscape($ar["CONTROL_ID"])?>')">
                                                        <?if (isset($ar["FILE"]) && !empty($ar["FILE"]["SRC"])):?>
                                                            <span class="bx_filter_btn_color_icon" style="background-image:url('<?=$ar["FILE"]["SRC"]?>');"></span>
                                                        <?endif?>
                                                        <span class="bx_filter_param_text">
                                                            <?=$ar["VALUE"]?>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </li>
                                            <?endforeach?>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?
                                break;
                            case "K"://RADIO_BUTTONS
                                ?>
                                <label class="bx_filter_param_label" for="<? echo "all_".$arCur["CONTROL_ID"] ?>">
                                    <span class="bx_filter_input_checkbox">
                                        <input
                                            type="radio"
                                            value=""
                                            name="<? echo $arCur["CONTROL_NAME_ALT"] ?>"
                                            id="<? echo "all_".$arCur["CONTROL_ID"] ?>"
                                            onclick="smartFilter.click(this)"
                                        />
                                        <span class="bx_filter_param_text"><? echo GetMessage("CT_BCSF_FILTER_ALL"); ?></span>
                                    </span>
                                </label>
                                <?foreach($arItem["VALUES"] as $val => $ar):?>
                                    <label data-role="label_<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>" class="bx_filter_param_label" for="<? echo $ar["CONTROL_ID"] ?>">
                                        <span class="bx_filter_input_checkbox <? echo $ar["DISABLED"] ? 'disabled': '' ?>">
                                            <input
                                                type="radio"
                                                value="<? echo $ar["HTML_VALUE_ALT"] ?>"
                                                name="<? echo $ar["CONTROL_NAME_ALT"] ?>"
                                                id="<? echo $ar["CONTROL_ID"] ?>"
                                                <? echo $ar["CHECKED"]? 'checked="checked"': '' ?>
                                                onclick="smartFilter.click(this)"
                                            />
                                            <span class="bx_filter_param_text" title="<?=$ar["VALUE"];?>"><?=$ar["VALUE"];?><?
                                            if ($arParams["DISPLAY_ELEMENT_COUNT"] !== "N" && isset($ar["ELEMENT_COUNT"])):
                                                ?> (<span data-role="count_<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>"><? echo $ar["ELEMENT_COUNT"]; ?></span>)<?
                                            endif;?></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </label>
                                <?endforeach;?>
                                <?
                                break;
                            case "U"://CALENDAR
                                ?>
                                <div class="bx_filter_parameters_box_container_block"><div class="bx_filter_input_container bx_filter_calendar_container">
                                    <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                                        'bitrix:main.calendar',
                                        '',
                                        array(
                                            'FORM_NAME' => $arResult["FILTER_NAME"]."_form",
                                            'SHOW_INPUT' => 'Y',
                                            'INPUT_ADDITIONAL_ATTR' => 'class="calendar" placeholder="'.FormatDate("SHORT", $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["VALUE"]).'" onkeyup="smartFilter.keyup(this)" onchange="smartFilter.keyup(this)"',
                                            'INPUT_NAME' => $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["CONTROL_NAME"],
                                            'INPUT_VALUE' => $arItem["VALUES"]["MIN"]["HTML_VALUE"],
                                            'SHOW_TIME' => 'N',
                                            'HIDE_TIMEBAR' => 'Y',
                                        ),
                                        null,
                                        array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
                                    );?>
                                </div></div>
                                <div class="bx_filter_parameters_box_container_block"><div class="bx_filter_input_container bx_filter_calendar_container">
                                    <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                                        'bitrix:main.calendar',
                                        '',
                                        array(
                                            'FORM_NAME' => $arResult["FILTER_NAME"]."_form",
                                            'SHOW_INPUT' => 'Y',
                                            'INPUT_ADDITIONAL_ATTR' => 'class="calendar" placeholder="'.FormatDate("SHORT", $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["VALUE"]).'" onkeyup="smartFilter.keyup(this)" onchange="smartFilter.keyup(this)"',
                                            'INPUT_NAME' => $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["CONTROL_NAME"],
                                            'INPUT_VALUE' => $arItem["VALUES"]["MAX"]["HTML_VALUE"],
                                            'SHOW_TIME' => 'N',
                                            'HIDE_TIMEBAR' => 'Y',
                                        ),
                                        null,
                                        array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
                                    );?>
                                </div></div>
                                <?
                                break;
                            default://CHECKBOXES
                                ?>
                                <?foreach($arItem["VALUES"] as $val => $ar):?>
                                    <label data-role="label_<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>" class="bx_filter_param_label <? echo $ar["DISABLED"] ? 'disabled': '' ?>" for="<? echo $ar["CONTROL_ID"] ?>">
                                        <span class="bx_filter_input_checkbox">
                                            <input
                                                type="checkbox"
                                                value="<? echo $ar["HTML_VALUE"] ?>"
                                                name="<? echo $ar["CONTROL_NAME"] ?>"
                                                id="<? echo $ar["CONTROL_ID"] ?>"
                                                <? echo $ar["CHECKED"]? 'checked="checked"': '' ?>
                                                onclick="smartFilter.click(this)"
                                            />
                                            <span class="bx_filter_param_text" title="<?=$ar["VALUE"];?>"><?=$ar["VALUE"];?><?
                                            if ($arParams["DISPLAY_ELEMENT_COUNT"] !== "N" && isset($ar["ELEMENT_COUNT"])):
                                                ?> (<span data-role="count_<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>"><? echo $ar["ELEMENT_COUNT"]; ?></span>)<?
                                            endif;?></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </label>
                                <?endforeach;?>
                        <?
                        }
                        ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clb"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?
            }
            ?>
            <div class="clb"></div>
            <div class="bx_filter_button_box active">
                <div class="bx_filter_block">
                    <div class="bx_filter_parameters_box_container">
                        <input class="bx_filter_search_button" type="submit" id="set_filter" name="set_filter" value="<?=GetMessage("CT_BCSF_SET_FILTER")?>" />
                        <input class="bx_filter_search_reset" type="submit" id="del_filter" name="del_filter" value="<?=GetMessage("CT_BCSF_DEL_FILTER")?>" />

                        <div class="bx_filter_popup_result left" id="modef" <?if(!isset($arResult["ELEMENT_COUNT"])) echo 'style="display:none"';?> style="display: inline-block;">
                            <?echo GetMessage("CT_BCSF_FILTER_COUNT", array("#ELEMENT_COUNT#" => '<span id="modef_num">'.intval($arResult["ELEMENT_COUNT"]).'</span>'));?>
                            <span class="arrow"></span>
                            <a href="<?echo $arResult["FILTER_URL"]?>"><?echo GetMessage("CT_BCSF_FILTER_SHOW")?></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var smartFilter = new JCSmartFilter('<?echo CUtil::JSEscape($arResult["FORM_ACTION"])?>', 'horizontal');
</script>

